# Do I need any further assumption to derive the distribution of likelihood ratio

Tags: distributions, likelihood-ratio

So I am trying to derive the distribution of likelihood ratio, $\Lambda$ under a given hypothesis $H_0$.
But all I'm given is that $Pr(\Lambda \geq x | H_0) = 1/x$. I cant help but feel that the problem is missing some assumptions. If not, how do I proceed ?

Comment: That gives you 1 - the CDF of the likelihood ratio at $x$ (assuming the distribution is continuous).  From that you should be able to derive the PDF of $\Lambda$.

Comment: @jbowman, I find it quite weird because originally what I did was to call the CDF of the likelihood ratio $F_{Y}(y)$ to be $1/x$ for $y \geq x$ and $1 - 1/x$ for $y < x$. And we know that PDF is the first derivative of the CDF. But i end up with a negative term, which is weird.

Comment: How do you end up with a negative term?  The derivative of $-1/x$ is $1/x^2$...